# What is the difference between Adding UIView on Storyboard OR on Storyboard Upper Bar?

Tags: uiview, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, subview

When i drag and drop a UIView on storyboard and when i do the same on the Storyboard Upper BAR. (where we generally find 3 options)
A. Name of the class.
B. First Responder.
C. Exit.

So it seems it is used just to provide a good symmetry in storyboard and to keep the things nice and clean.

I have been looking for it for many days but no where i find anything about this particularly.

I have done it like below:

from assistant editor i create an object named ScoreCardView. (there is one more view, due to scrollview, and then tableView).

```
_ScoreCardView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight-50);

_ScoreCardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

_ScoreCardView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

[self.view addSubview:_ScoreCardView];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_ScoreCardView];
```

I want it to rotate landscape(even in portrait mode), but tab bar would remain as it is.

Its working fine if a use UIView on the storyboard itself, but not with (UIView extension view ?)

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is when you add view on your controller you need not to add view to the controller's view. On the other hand if you add that view on the top bar of the controller you have to add that view as subview using code:

self.view.addSubview(viewToAdd)

Thanks.